# What would this phone number regex look like?

Tags: regex

`(555) 555 - 5555`

Everything above would be required - spacing and all.

Comment: `\(555\) 555 - 555` you said "everything above".

Comment: @WTP, well this is really a simple shot! lol

Comment: Check out [Regex Library](http://www.regexlib.net) - it has **tons** of sample regexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
/\(\d{3}\) \d{3} - \d{4}/
```

Answer (score 1):

see below example, only (555) 555 - 5555 will be grepped out:

```
kent$  cat a
(555) 555 - 5555
(5554) 555 - 5555
(555)555 - 5555
(555) 5554 - 5555
(555) 555 - 55554
(555)555 - 5555555

kent$  grep -P "^\(\d{3}\) \d{3} - \d{4}$" a
(555) 555 - 5555
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.  For example, `/\(\d{3}\)\ \d{3}\ \-\ \d{4}/`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
(1-3 digits) 2-3 digits - 4-6 digits
```

would be:

```
^\(\d{1,3}\) \d{2,3} - \d{4,6}$
```

You can adjust the allowed number of digits according to your needs.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.